# Viewport userscalable for laptop/desktop

Tags: html, user-controls, viewport, meta, zooming

Is there any way to restrict the user to zoom in/out on a webpage, on laptop/desktop

I tried working out the below code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, 
      minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

That works fine on mobile but fails on laptop/desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The viewport meta tag doesn't affect desktop browsers. It is purely for targeting mobile browsers.

You can use the following CSS to *try* and prevent text zooming in desktop browsers:

```
<style type="text/css">
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
-ms-text-size-adjust:none;
-moz-text-size-adjust:none;
text-size-adjust:none;
</style>
```

However, this is experimental only and widely unsupported; See Moz Developer Network:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust

Personally, I think that preventing a user from zooming in a browser will lead to awful accessibility. Some users **need** to zoom in to consume content on the web.

If you're interested in creating a webpage that functions correctly and is still accessible, check out the W3 accessibility guidelines: http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/accessibility.php and check your pages with Wave:http://wave.webaim.org/